# 〜ということ and just 〜こと

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I've been trying to learn when to use 〜ということ or just 〜こと, for example:

> 彼が金を貸してくれた{ということ/ こと}は私は彼に信用されている{ということ/こと}だ。 (The fact that he lent
> me money means that I am trusted by him.)

With the above example what combinations of ということは/ことは and  ということだ/ことだ are possible? Also how about in general?

> (e.g. 彼が金を貸してくれたということ は私は彼に信用されていることだ。,
>
> 彼が金を貸してくれたことは私は彼に信用されているということだ。etc.)

Answer (score 9):

In expressing:

> "A means/implies B (after all, in essence, etc.)",

it is only very common, grammatical and natural to use 「ということ」 ***back-to-back*** among us native speakers.  (If it is taught otherwise in Japanese as a foreign language, that is too bad.)

> 「(Mini-Sentence A) ということ**は** (Mini-Sentence B) ということ**だ / である**。」

Applying this to your example sentence, you will have:

> 「彼が金を貸してくれた**ということ**は、私は彼に信用されている**ということ**だ。」

Replace either one of the two ということ's with just こと and the sentence will not sound nearly as natural or correct.