# Why is の used here instead of こと?

Tags: grammar, sentence

On a grammar website (that tries to use somewhat more literal translations) I came across this sentence:

彼が出席しなかった**というのは**、よほどのことがあったんだろうね。

**The fact that** he did not attend must mean that there were inordinate circumstances.

It is my understanding that というのは is used more for subjective conclusions and interpretations, like perhaps “the fact that he has been calling you recently **is odd**” rather than a sentence like “the fact that he hasn’t arrived yet **must mean** he got caught in traffic” which sounds more objective and I would expect ということは.

In fact putting the translation of the original sentence into DeepL yields the exact same JP sentence but with こと instead of の. I know の can stand in for こと as well sometimes but it also can sound more subjective.
Is this a case where either is natural, or is there some other nuance at play, perhaps because of the んだろう at the end?

Comment: Related [の ⋆ こと ⋆ というの ⋆ ということ Used as Complementizers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82547)

Comment: There may be subtle differences, but they are so subtle that even native speakers can't really put the differences into words. Practically they can be considered more or less interchangeable. I don't quite agree with the distinction mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, replacing の with こと doesn't change the meaning much.

> 彼が出席しなかった**ということ**は、よほどのことがあったんだろうね。

Because of という, however, this sounds like the speaker is trying to logically draw some conclusion based on what they have learned.

Removing という results in an unnatural sentence.

> [x] 彼が出席しなかった**こと**は、よほどのことがあったんだろうね。

Also, ということ sounds weird if the main clause is merely the speaker's impression.

> [x] 彼が出席しなかった**ということ**は、珍しいね。

It's hard to pinpoint what exactly the の in the original sentence refers to. I would understand it as the whole circumstances that led to his absence, rather than (just) the objective fact that he didn't attend.

> 彼が出席しなかった**というの**は、よほどのことがあったんだろうね。

という is totally optional.

> 彼が出席しなかった**の**は、よほどのことがあったんだろうね。

The following sentence is also fine.

> 彼が出席しなかった**というの**は、珍しいね。