# Understanding a usage of ってこと

Tags: translation, colloquial-language

From the first episode of Death Note:

> フッ… 楽に死なせたり苦しませて死なせたり できるって**こと**か

I know the quoted part (up to and including って) means something like:

> "one can let them die easily or let them suffer and die painfully"

What is the こと doing here? Is it turning it into something like:

> It says, "one can let them die easily or let them suffer and die painfully"?

If that's the case, why isn't こと marked with が or は?

Comment: So that means... ?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93001/45489

Comment: @JimmyYang  That would mean "こと" is the subject of the sentence, right? So why doesn't it have a が or は particle marking it? Also, the sentence lacks a verb or copula at the end of it, which is also confusing.

Comment: こと simply normalizes the entire「楽に死なせたり苦しませて死なせたり できる」. It is similar to how のだ normalizes the full sentence before it.

Comment: I think what you are missing is the first sentence omits *that means*.